# push UIViewcontroller to UINavigation Controller

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, viewcontroller

I have login screen and forgot password screen.forgot password screen is connect to the navigation controller but my login screen not connect to the navigation controller so how to move login screen to forgot screen

[image]
here is my code

```
forgotpasswod *secondViewController =
    [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"forgotpasswodpage"];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:secondViewController animated:YES];
```

Comment: show your storyborad scene

Comment: i have a login and forgot vc.login vc dows not connect navogationcontroller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to move ViewController to Navigation Viewcontroller than use presentView Controller.

paste this code in your action method

```
- (IBAction)forgotpassword:(id)sender {

    forgotpasswod *secondViewController =
    [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"forgotpasswodpage"];

    UINavigationController *controller = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:secondViewController];
    [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

when you try this code than also you can change navigation bar color

```
if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) <= NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1) {
        // iOS 6.1 or earlier
        self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithHexString:@"#37B578"];
    } else {
        // iOS 7.0 or later
        self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor colorWithHexString:@"#37B578"];
        self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
    }
```

ok try this code and tell me what happen...

Answer (score 1):

You can present View controller

```
let vc : ForgotPassword = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("forgotView") as  ForgotPassword

let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)

self.presentViewController(navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

for obj c

```
 ForgotPassword *secondViewController =
[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"forgotpasswodpage"];

UINavigationController *controller = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:secondViewController];
[self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that your navigation controller is nil, since the initial controller (LoginViewController) is not embedded in a navigation controller like the forgorpassordViewController.

Why don't you embed your loginInViewController in a navigationController and set an Identifier on the ForgotViewController to 'forgotpasswodpage' just as you've done

Then you do exactly what is in your code

```
forgotpasswod *secondViewController =
    (forgotpasswod *)[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"forgotpasswodpage"];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:secondViewController animated:YES];
```

Also I prefer you use [self.navigationController showViewController:secondViewController animated:YES];

Answer (score 0):

On click of forgot password,simply make navigation controller from your story board your app's window's rootview controller. It will automatically load view attached to your navigation controller.